# Convert pandas data frame to JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have the following data frame in pandas and I am looking to convert it into a JSON variable. Below is an example of the data that I have:

```
     DOCDATE   GLPOSTDT  CURTRXAM Customer_Code Reference Doc Type  Status                 Customer_Name    CRLMTAMT
0 2016-04-07 2016-04-07    525.88          ADHA   3859502      INV  Active  ADDO HARDWARE AND FURNISHERS   400000.00
1 2016-04-11 2016-04-11   9616.65          ADHA   3861622      INV  Active  ADDO HARDWARE AND FURNISHERS   400000.00
2 2016-04-28 2016-04-29  -5048.80          ADHA   0339942      PYM  Active  ADDO HARDWARE AND FURNISHERS   400000.00
3 2016-02-29 2016-02-29 -10462.36          CHMO  01728560      DED   Legal           CHECKIN SUPERMARKET 14500000.00
4 2016-04-20 2016-04-20  12727.87          CHMO   3871124      INV   Legal           CHECKIN SUPERMARKET 14500000.00
5 2016-04-20 2016-04-20   2640.92          CHMO   3871134      INV   Legal           CHECKIN SUPERMARKET 14500000.00
```

The output that I am looking for is as follows:

```
Customer1 = {
  "Customer_code" : "ADHA",
  "Status" : "Active",
  "CRLMTAMT" : "400000",
  "Customer_Name" : "ADDO HARDWARE AND FURNISHERS",
  "Transactions" : {
    "INV" : {
      "3859502" : {
        "GLPOSTDT" : "2016-04-07",
        "CURTRXAM" : "525.88"
      },
      "3861622" : {
        "GLPOSTDT" : "2016-04-11",
        "CURTRXAM" : "9616.65"
      }
    },
    "PYM" : {
      "0339942" : {
        "GLPOSTDT" : "2016-04-29",
        "CURTRXAM" : "-5048.80"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The "Transactions' leg of the JSON variable is split into the different "Doc Types". Then using the "Reference" field I would apply the corresponding "GLPOSTDT" and "CURTRXAM".
After the first customer has been created I would then write it to a DB and then loop to the next customer (Customer_code = "CHMO") but I am having trouble converting/grouping each Customer_code from the pandas df into a JSON variable

Comment: There is no JSON type in python. Looks like you want a dictionary?

Comment: Essentially yes, I would then be able to dump the dictionary to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
dict_of_dataframe = dataframe.to_dict(orient='dict')
with open('result.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(dict_of_dataframe, fp)
```